# How to preserve color in *Messages* buffer?

Tags: faces, message, logging

When running (`C-x C-e`) the following snippet and doing `M-x mes`, I see `text` written in red in the minibuffer area, but the text in the `*Messages*` buffer is stripped of all formatting.

```
(defun mes ()
  "message me"
  (interactive)
  (message (propertize "text" 'face 'font-lock-warning-face)))
```

How can I preserve the color and other font information in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: The color you see is actually in the echo area, not the `*Messages*` buffer -- so there is nothing to preserve.  You'd need an entirely different approach to place overlays or text properties in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't with `message`. Having looked at the internals of `message`, only the raw char* is given to the function that actually logs the text, all text properties are lost.

You can hack your way around this by writing a function that:

- calls `message` with `message-log-max` let-bound to nil so that it won't log to `*Messages*`
- manually inserts the propertized string at the end of the messages buffer by let-binding `inhibit-read-only` to `t` in the message buffer.

Here is an implementation:

```lisp
(defun my-message (format &rest args)
  "Acts like `message' but preserves string properties in the *Messages* buffer."
  (let ((message-log-max nil))
    (apply 'message format args))
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*Messages*")
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (unless (zerop (current-column)) (insert "\n"))
        (insert (apply 'format format args))
        (insert "\n")))))
```